# Question on Math Test

Tags: probability

If the birth of a boy is just as likely as the birth of a girl, and a family has $4 $children, which outcome is most likely?

- $4$ boys
- $4$ girls
- $3$ girls $1$ boy
- $3$ boys $1$ girl
- $2$ boys $2$ girls
- All of the above

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There's 16 equally likely possibilities, listed below. Whichever outcome corresponds to the most possibilities is the most likely.

- GGGG
- GGGB
- GGBG
- GGBB
- GBGG
- GBGB
- GBBG
- GBBB
- BGGG
- BGGB
- BGBG
- BGBB
- BBGG
- BBGB
- BBBG
- BBBB

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to have 4 boys (BBBB) or 4 girls (GGGG). But there 4 ways to have 3G/1B (GGGB, GGBG, GBGG, GBBB) or 1G/3B. And there are 6 ways to have 2G/2B (GGBB, GBGB, GBBG, BGGB, BGBG, BBGG).

Hence the answer is 2G/2B.